# Read input from console and perform some operation using java

Tags: java

I Have 3 input and sum that take an input and if sum is 180, it print yes and if it is less
than 180 it print NO.

```
3 
40 40 100
45 45 90
180 1 1
```

> Above 3 means 3 row input that three row contain different value.

To perform this activity I have written the below function but its test case is wrong. How can I perform this function using Scanner.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CodeChef {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value of A");
        int A = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter value of B");
        int B = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter value of AC");
        int C  = sc.nextInt();
        
        if (A+B+C == 180) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        }else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As an aside, I noticed that in all your question you prefix all the non-code text with `>`. That makes your text a blockquote. Please don't do that unless you're actually quoting something.

Comment: Regarding your question, what should the first row represent? The number of rows you have to read? You're ignoring it and you're basically reading 3, 40, 40 and ignoring the rest of the input. Which of course skews the results if the test expect you to read something else (which you didn't specify, by the way).

Comment: What it that '3' on its own? If it's for the number of inputs, it's really redundant